# Python (Pandas) - I created a Variable and want to use it to make charts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I am working on The Titanic's passenger database. I would like to pull data for only male passengers, and compare survival rates based on whether the male passenger had a spouse or child.

I managed to pull just male info using this code:

```
male_over_18 = df[ (df['Sex'] == 'male') & (df['Age'] >=18) ]
```

I want to take the new male over 18 data that I created and use it to create charts. I would like to input it into this swarm plot or histogram but when I use the variable name `male_over_18` it doesn't work. I've included the code for the charts below:

```
sns.swarmplot(x='SibSp',y='Parch',hue="male_over_18",data=df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document of seaborn:

`Parameters: x, y, hue: names of variables in data or vector data`

This means your `swarmplot` call will look for a column named 'male_over_18' in `df` for hue, which is not what you want.

You can call `sns.swarmplot(x='SibSp',y='Parch',data=male_over_18)` instead to plot 'SibSp' against 'Parch' column for males over 18.

If you want to plot with hue, you need another column to represent hue, say 'Age': `sns.swarmplot(x='SibSp',y='Parch',hue='Age',data=male_over_18)`